# How to submit form with jQuery .submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have the following code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" id="theform" action="http://example.com" target="_blank">
        <input name="email" placeholder="email" type="text">
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                jQuery('#theform').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                //Code here
                jQuery('#theform').removeAttr('disabled').submit();
            }
        });

    });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The form does not submit. Any idea what is up?

I know I could do an `ajax` call to manually submit the form to action URL and then use `JavaScript` to redirect to where I want to send the user in a new tab; however, I don't want to do that because `popup blockers` will eat up the `JavaScript` redirect. Hence, I have the form `target="_blank"` upon `submit`, which gets the user where I want to send them... if only the code worked.

Comment: Any Error in Console?

Comment: @Tushar No error in console

Comment: Ajax Request in `Network` tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the line `e.preventDefault();` from your onclick event handler.

Update:
Sorry my bad that I didn't notice that you were explicitly trying to submit  the form later in the code. Even though the above change will fix it, the actual issue is else where. Don't make any changes to the function just rename the submit button's id to something else and update the binding and the code should work.
Working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/epednoat/

```
<body>
    <form method="post" id="theform" action="http://example.com" target="_blank">
        <input name="email" placeholder="email" type="text">
        <input id="smt" type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('#smt').on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                jQuery('#theform').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                //Code here
                jQuery('#theform').removeAttr('disabled').submit();
            }
        });

    });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You genius, I could kiss you. This works. Mind explaining? I thought I wanted to stop the submit of the form, hence the e.preventDefault(); after the click.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Now my code works flawlessly -- thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can [jQuery submit](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) form with below code.

```
$( "#theform" ).submit(function( event ) {
  alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

**With JavaScript**

```
function submitform()
{
  document.theform.submit();
}
```

Comment: Tried that. It creates a loop when I go to .submit() later on.